# How Do I Setup SSL in my webserver

Tags: php, ssl

my blog loads fine if I use the http protocol. It leads to a not found page when I use https. How do I enable https (or SSL) in my webserver?

http://fuwafuwa.byethost9.com // works fine
https://fuwafuwa.byethost9.com //not working

Answer (score 1):

If you're hosting using IIS, you can donwload the [IIS 6.0 Resource Kit Tools](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/840671) that contains a SelfSSL tool that can help you create and install a SSL certificate. 
Of course it doesn't come from a trusted source, so if you want it for testing your app, that's fine.

Otherwise you should probably get one from a trusted authority like VeriSign (for example).

Answer (score 1):

SSL needs to explicitly be turned on in the server configuration. In Apache, you can enable another virtual host (in addition to one on the standard port 80) and set it to run on port 443 for HTTPS.

You additionally need an SSL certificate, which will cost money (unless you opt for a self-signed cert). Unless you pay for a real certificate, users of the HTTPS site well get scary warnings about invalid certificates.

Comment: how do I do that in a CPanel? sorry, I really am a total noob:(

Comment: From what I can tell, you may not be able to do this in CPanel.

Comment: so that means I have to get a certificate for a live site...

Answer (score 1):

You will need to get with your hosting provider and ask them to generate a Certificate Signing Request (CSR).  You will then need to take this and give it to an SSL certificate vendor such as Verisign or GoDaddy and purchase the certificate.  Once they have verified the request they will issue the signed certificate.  You will then need to provide the signed certificate to your hosting provider so that they can install it on the server and enable SSL for the web site.  Keep in mind you will also need a dedicated IP address instead of using a shared IP address, so there may be additional fees from your hosting provider for both the dedicated address and the setup time if they don't provide automated tools.